# Words that estimate numerical proportions of a group

Tags: reporting

There seem to be more than a few papers that surround the use of certain words to define the probability of an event without actually using the numerical probability itself.

For example, if you are certain that something is going to happen, the probability of the event is 100%. If you are almost certain, the probability of the event is 93% +/- 6%.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_of_estimative_probability

In election terminology, we have words like majority, plurality, minority, some fraction - majority/minority. These words are easy to convert to numeric proportions (in most cases).

With those examples in mind are there any papers or generally accepted conventions for words like "many, most, few, some" that act as a guideline for numerical proportions associated with those words?

Comment: It's a good question (and may have some discipline-specific answers in addition to certain [legal interpretations](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Preponderance+of+Evidence)), but my personal opinion is that it's usually a mistake to shoehorn inherently qualitative assessments into a pseudo-quantitative language because it will only deceive others concerning the fuzzy nature of what is being asserted.

Comment: I agree strongly with @whuber. That said, see http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ss/1177012242

Comment: @Nick Nice reference! I think my position may be represented in the comment by Wallsten and Budescu, quoted by Mosteller and Youtz in their [rejoinder](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.ss/1177012251): "Probability phrases have vague meanings to individuals. Any attempt to render them precise will of necessity overlook the important semantic role of this vagueness."

Comment: That paper is about probability, whereas I'm interested in proportion... conventions/papers surrounding statements about the size of a group not the probability of an outcome. Which is what that paper discusses ("numerical averages of opinions on quantitative meanings of 52 qualitative probabilistic expressions"). I want to know numerical averages of opinions on quantitative meanings of XX qualitative *proportional* expressions. ie, Some, many, most, all, few... etc.

Comment: The point is that many issues concerning probability statements attach, *mutatis mutandis,* to statements about proportions.

Comment: @whuber agreed, I'm just having trouble finding any research for proportions like there is for probability.

Comment: I am not sure what "research" would be here except of the Mosteller type, namely asking people to quantify. What's trivial but perhaps worth emphasis is how often people write "most" when their evidence only supports "many". As a matter of English usage I'd assert few < many < most < all. But most implies many, even if the converse isn't true. Some seems the most context-dependent. Even "all" can in context mean "almost all". But where do you stop? "All" in "all right-thinking people agree ..." isn't really a quantification, as it adds nothing of substance to "right-thinking people".

Comment: Small, peripheral note: In formal logic, "some" means *at least one*. Eg, $\exists x (Dx\wedge Cx)$ is "some dogs are clever" (hypertechnically "there exists at least one thing such that it is a dog and it is clever"). See [here](http://rip94550.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/logic-all-and-some/).